# How to connect models between two projects with same database in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

How to take models from project 1 to project 2 in django, both projects sharing same database

Comment: what you have been tried so far ?

Comment: I am trying,. In views. Py add these line of code 'from project1. app. models import Product '. And also add project1. app inside installed apps in project2

Comment: Add these code to your question not in the commnent

Comment: For doing  microservice I want to important models from project1 to protect

Answer (score -1):

This can be done, although confused to why?. Is there a specific reason to why you are looking to use two projects, rather than integrating multiple apps in the one Django project?

1. Point both projects to the same database in `settings.py`
2. Take the models from project 1 and copy to project 2.
3. You should be able to query the models as normal